# Control space between lines

Tags: line-spacing

I have need to control line spaces in the certification page that has following format:

```
Line 1.1
Line 1.2
Line 2.1
Line 2.2
...
Line n.1
Line n.2
```

(These are short lines.) I need to single space between lines `x.1` and `x.2` but double space for the rest. I tried putting

```
Line x.1
\singlespacing
Line x.2
```

But the gap between 2 lines becomes very big. What's the right way to format this?

Thanks,

Comment: `\begin{singlespace}...\end{singlespace}` will limit the effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `singlespace` environment to limit the effect. There are `onehalfspace` and `doublespace` environments as well.

Please note that there's a `singlespace*` environment as well, which does **not** add a `\vskip\baselineskip` at the beginning.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
All

is

doublespaced

here
\begin{singlespace}
But

here

only

singlespaced
\end{singlespace}
Double

spacing

again

here



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sweet. that works! Will have to wait a few minutes before accepting though. You're just too fast :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Or like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
Line 1.1\\
Line 1.2

Line 2.1\\
Line 2.2

Line n.1\\
Line n.2
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```